# How to iterate through LINQ dataset in WPF with count as part of query?

Tags: wpf, linq, count, loops

I am new to C# and this is completely stumping me. I have a WPF form with many textboxes that are used to to spatially represent the number of services required in each area (`PropertyZone`) of a map.

I can write a LINQ query that brings back all of my necessary data into a `DataGrid`, but I have been completely unable to access the data beyond that. I have attempted to dump the data into a `DataTable`, to no avail. I can see the data in the `DataGrid`, but I do not know how to iterate through the rows. I do not care if I use a `DataGrid`, `DataTable`, `Collection` or any other method to access the data. In stumbling around a `Collection` seems like it might be a good solution, but the use of `inner join`s and a `count()` seems to be my downfall.

There are two columns of data being produced:

```
Column1=PropertyZone 
Column2=CountOfServicesInThatPropertyZone
```

I want to look at `Column1` `Row1` and based on this value, dump the value from `Column2` `Row1` into a textbox with the same name as the value in `Column1` `Row1` and do this for all rows in each of the two columns.

This is the LINQ query that does work, but I have been completely unable to access the data.

```
var query =
      from o in con.ORDER_LINE_TABLEs
      join p in con.PROPERTY_TABLEs on o.PropertyNumber equals p.PropertyNumber 
      where o.ServiceNumber == 2
      group o by p.PropertyZone into g
      select new { PropertyZone = g.Key, CountOfServicesInThatPropertyZone = g.Count() };
ServiceDataGrid.ItemsSource = query;
```

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access an item in particular, you have to run the query and store the results somewhere, for example inside a List. You can then bind the DataGrid to this same List:

```
var query =
  from o in con.ORDER_LINE_TABLEs
  join p in con.PROPERTY_TABLEs on o.PropertyNumber equals p.PropertyNumber 
  where o.ServiceNumber == 2
  group o by p.PropertyZone into g
  select new { PropertyZone = g.Key, CountOfServicesInThatPropertyZone = g.Count() };

var myList = query.ToList();

ServiceDataGrid.ItemsSource = myList;

var row1Col1Value = myList[0].PropertyZone;
var row1Col2Value = myList[0].CountOfServicesInThatPropertyZone;
```

Comment: You are awesome, I can't believe it was that easy, that was probably the easiest question you have ever answered. Thank you very much.